# iOS - How can the VoIP call screen be configured? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voip, callkit

I am working on an iOS VoIP app, and i've noticed that, apart from setting up the app's logo, there is not much configuration allowed for the call screen as CallKit uses the iOS default one.

So i was curious on how does RoboKiller accomplish to show the caller's information on the VoIP call screen. Like on the following image: [robokiller screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFHi6.png)

Obviously i imagine the data itself comes from some sort of service of their own, but how can that info be embedded into the default call screen?

Comment: did you find out how to get a screen like your attachment for Robokiller?

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the native CallKit UI. I haven't used RoboKiller but I suppose that the screenshot you've linked is a screen inside the app itself that is simply similar to the native one.