# Is it possible to p customize the voip call screen?

Tags: ios, callkit

I'm implemented an experimental poc app to experiment with voip pushes/calls etc.

When the app receives a voip push there's a call screen that gets displayed, however its very basic not to mention unprofessional looking. Is there anyway to customize this to show additional info on the calling screen?

Comment: This is a system screen which cannot be customized. The picture is gonna be displayed if the info from `CXHandle`, e.g. phone number, will match some saved contact from Contacts app.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit), CallKit manages the call UI screens, and as such these can not be modified.

You can however make your own custom call screen like for ex. Apps like Zoom and WhatsApp do. This however comes with the complication of having to handle system events on your own and will not fit in a stackoverflow answer.

Also answered here: [iOS - How can the VoIP call screen be configured? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289119/ios-how-can-the-voip-call-screen-be-configured-is-it-possible)

Comment: "You can however make your own custom call screen".  Where is the iOS documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, You cant modify the incoming call screen of CallKit. But when user receives the call, the control get handled over to your own app, where you can show whatever you want for currently running app(just like whatsapp, skype etc).

For Incoming call screen, you can only show the values that are in `CXCallUpdate`(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallupdate). Here, you can modify user's localized name, remoteHandle(for showing phonenumber/email address of the caller), and you can give boolean values to other properties of `CXCallUpdate` based on what your call supports. Thats it.

You might have checked all other VOIP call apps, you must not have found any app having custom incoming call screens(If by chance if they have, then it must not be working in background, I mean it must not be working in combination with PushKit).